# How to filter by a list of values in a WFS request?

Tags: wfs, filter, function, getfeature

I'm using the following GetFeature POST request (to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs`) trying to query the sample "bugsites" layer that ships with GeoServer. The request is supposed to return the features whose `cat` attribute is contained in the given set of literals:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wfs:GetFeature
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
    xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
    outputFormat="application/json"
>
    <wfs:Query typeNames="sf:bugsites">
        <fes:Filter>
            <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <fes:ValueReference>cat</fes:ValueReference>
                <fes:Function name="in">
                    <fes:Literal>19</fes:Literal>
                    <fes:Literal>20</fes:Literal>
                    <fes:Literal>21</fes:Literal>
                </fes:Function>
            </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </fes:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

However, no features are being returned:

```json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [],
    "totalFeatures": 0,
    "numberMatched": 0,
    "numberReturned": 0,
    "timeStamp": "2024-02-29T08:57:26.888Z",
    "crs": null
}
```

When using a GET request along with the Common Query Language (CQL) on the other hand ...

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs
    ?service=WFS
    &version=2.0.0
    &request=GetFeature
    &typeNames=sf:bugsites
    &outputFormat=application/json
    &cql_filter=cat%20IN%20(19,20,21)
```

([clickable link](http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=sf:bugsites&outputFormat=application/json&cql_filter=cat%20IN%20(19,20,21)))

..., I do get the three features returned:

```json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "bugsites.19",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    591224,
                    4919553
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "the_geom",
            "properties": {
                "cat": 19,
                "str1": "Beetle site"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "bugsites.20",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    591306,
                    4920512
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "the_geom",
            "properties": {
                "cat": 20,
                "str1": "Beetle site"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "bugsites.21",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    591339,
                    4915303
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "the_geom",
            "properties": {
                "cat": 21,
                "str1": "Beetle site"
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalFeatures": 3,
    "numberMatched": 3,
    "numberReturned": 3,
    "timeStamp": "2024-02-29T09:06:13.801Z",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::26713"
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to use POST requests (for one, because the list of literals in the actual request might get quite large).

What is wrong with the first request?

**EDIT:**

It seems like the filters are being converted differently. Here's what I'm getting for the first (the POST) request in the `geoserver.log` file:

```
29 Feb 10:39:36 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 2.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    outputFormat = application/json
    resolve = none
    resolveDepth = *
    resolveTimeout = 300
    resultType = results
    abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.QueryTypeImpl@1cc3c1a3 (handle: null) (abstractProjectionClause: null, abstractSelectionClause: [ cat = in([19], [20], [21]) ], abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{http://www.openplans.org/spearfish}bugsites]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: null, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
    abstractQueryExpression[0]:
        abstractSelectionClause = [ cat = in([19], [20], [21]) ]
        typeNames[0] = {http://www.openplans.org/spearfish}bugsites
        filter = [ cat = in([19], [20], [21]) ]
29 Feb 10:39:36 INFO   [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
```

For the second (the GET) request, the following information is written:

```
29 Feb 10:39:52 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 2.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    outputFormat = application/json
    resolve = none
    resolveDepth = *
    resolveTimeout = 300
    resultType = results
    abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.QueryTypeImpl@172d6f57 (handle: null) (abstractProjectionClause: null, abstractSelectionClause: [[ cat = 20 ] OR [ cat = 21 ]], abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{http://www.openplans.org/spearfish}bugsites]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: null, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
    abstractQueryExpression[0]:
        abstractSelectionClause = [[ cat = 20 ] OR [ cat = 21 ]]
        typeNames[0] = {http://www.openplans.org/spearfish}bugsites
        filter = [[ cat = 20 ] OR [ cat = 21 ]]
29 Feb 10:39:52 INFO   [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
```

The POST request seems to try to match against single-element arrays.

But how would I use it correctly?